# Converting Array Keys to numbers node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the problem that i have an array like this :

```
var users = {
    'asidfjasd': {
       realname: 'John'  
    },
    'ggggggg': {
       realname: 'Peter'  
    }
}
```

And i want to access the users with

```
users[1]
```

to get

```
'ggggggg': {
       realname: 'Peter'  
}
```

Is there a way to do this with node.js?

**EDIT**

I have found a way to work around it by creating a second object with the usernames and them pointing to the id for the users-object.
This might not work for other applications but it did it for mine.

**CLOSED**

Comment: That example code will give you an error. It should be an object, and you need to separate the properties with a comma. Or make it an array.

Comment: my bad with the comma but what do you mean with should be an object.
I'm creating an array first and than a function creates a working object (the single users) and puts them into the array with a special key.

Comment: It's already an object (keys/values) but you're using array `[]` syntax. [It will give you an error](https://jsfiddle.net/s1z1n2b3/)

Comment: You can't put objects into an array "with a special key". Arrays use number-based indexes.

Comment: Is there a possibility to get the objects in the parent object to be numeric so i can loop through them without changing the actual key?

Comment: Basically you need to clarify what data structure you need _first_ but obeying the JS syntax, not making stuff up :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what it means to "get" `'ggggggg': { realname: 'Peter' }`. Do you mean you want to get an object with a single property whose name is `ggggggg`?

Comment: I'm sorry for missusing them. I'm quite new to java. The name of the child object is a socket.io id which i need directly accessable for other parts of the application. Now for looping through them and searching for the 'real name' i need them to be numeric.

Comment: @apsillers i mean that i want to rename ggggggg to 1 to access realname more easily

Comment: You need to edit your question so that it contains _all the relevant_ information. It's not clear what you want to do and this back and forth commentary isn't helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look more closely at the structures you want to use.

Objects can be accessible using their keys. Keys are unique and are unordered. I think your changed example is correct (I added in an extra property for use in a later example).

So...

```
var users = {
    'asidfjasd': {
       realname: 'John'  
    },
    'ggggggg': {
       realname: 'Peter'  
    },
    'aaaa': {
       realname: 'Peter'
    }
}

users.ggggggg // { realname: "Peter" }
users['ggggggg'] // { realname: "Peter" }
```

Now, it is possible to *iterate* over this using `Object.keys(users)`:

```
var keys = Object.keys(users);
```

To log names to the console you could do this:

```
keys.forEach(function (el) {
  console.log(users[el].realname);
});
```

To return an array of names you could do this:

```
var names = keys.map(function (el) {
  return users[el].realname;
});
```

How about turning your current data into an array you can access by numerical index:

```
var arrayOfObjs = keys.map(function (el) {
  return { socketname: el, realname: users[el].realname };
});
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  { "socketname": "asidfjasd", "realname": "John" },
  { "socketname": "ggggggg", "realname": "Peter" }
]
```

You can then use array methods to pull out the information you want from the objects. Say you want to get an array of objects where the realname is "Peter" assuming multiple "Peters" in the data:

```
var peters = arrayOfObjs.filter(function (el) {
  return el.realname === 'Peter';
});
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  { "socketname": "ggggggg", "realname": "Peter" },
  { "socketname": "aaaa", "realname": "Peter" }
]
```

[DEMO CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/s1z1n2b3/1/)